# Sync two async events in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

In my JavaScript App (jQuery) I have two events that are fired asynchronously:

- widget 1 fires "Event1" when finishes loading
- widget 2 fires "Event2" when finishes  loading

How do I "sync" these two async events in order to "call a method" only after these two events fired.

I would need an approach that works for multiple events also.

Comment: Use the callback function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use deferred objects.

```
var deferredObj1 = $.Deferred(),
    deferredObj2 = $.Deferred();

$.when(deferredObj1,deferredObj2).done(function(){
    console.log("They are both done!");
});

// inside the Event1 handler:
deferredObj1.resolve();

// inside the Event2 handler:
deferredObj2.resolve();
```

Comment: +1 beat me to it, was just reminding myself how this works. Just to add As of Jquery 1.5 `ajax` calls implement the `Promise` interface, presuming the asynchronous events in question are `ajax` this should be exactly what your after...

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at [`async.js`](https://github.com/caolan/async) which provides a very interesting and clean way of syncing the execution of asynchronous actions.

For example, the [`waterfall`](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) method allows you to chain asynchronous actions in a sequential order.

Such an execution looks pretty and simple in your real-life code :

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback){
        callback(null, 'one', 'two');
    },
    function(arg1, arg2, callback){
        callback(null, 'three');
    },
    function(arg1, callback){
        // arg1 now equals 'three'
        callback(null, 'done');
    }
], function (err, result) {
   // result now equals 'done'    
});
```

Comment: waterfall looks like really as jquery $.when or i misunderstood its purpose

Comment: This actually chains the calls so that the second runs after the first, the third after the second, etc.  This may or may not be desirable, depending on the circumstances.  The original code had both tasks started at the same time and able to run in any order.

Comment: @cHao sure, in this case nothing prevents you to use `async.parrallel` if you want your actions to run in parrallel.